# How to determine number of observations based on measurement frequency?

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, power-spectral-density, continuous-signals, measurement

So I'm working on a problem where I'm measuring a signal with two different instruments -- one is a low frequency measurement system (1 Hz), and the other is a high frequency measurement system (200 Hz). I am interested in the maximum of the signal (peak). Please see attached image.

[image: Comparison of two low freq and high freq system]

Now it's obvious that there's a loss of information when we're using a low freq measurement system than when using a high freq measurement system. However, if I take the maximum (peak) of both the signals, I only end up with 1 single observation. The peak could be impacted by noise.

But in reality, the maximum of the signal is a random variable itself. Therefore, the high frequency signal, should in reality be giving me multiple observations of the same quantity -- the max of the signal. This begets the question, **how do I decide on the number of observations that I have from this high frequency signal? Am I supposed to take all the observations within some region? If yes, then how do I decide that region? Is there any relationship between the frequency of measurement and the number of observations of the maximum?**

My knowledge of signal processing is limited, but I am well acquainted with Bayesian statistics.

Comment: Can you tell us something about the signal you're observing? You need to have a signal model (and you definitely assume one!) so that you can make any statement on the peak, even with your higher-frequency sampling device.

Comment: and you're modelling your random variable incorrectly: It's not 1 observation of a single real-valued variable, it's a 2D random variable: the value and the time of the maximum. You'd have to know the time before you can observe the height with a single measurement, but it doesn't sound like you know the time! With a signal model, and stochastics, you can derive a least-observation estimator (if you define an acceptable estimator variance, that is), or at least it allows us to help you with that :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MarcusMüller, you are right. It's a stochastic process (I'm assuming non stationary). In reality its a strain measurement as the moving load moves over the structure.

So, I need to make an assumption on the stationarity/non-stationarity of the process and use the estimator for the maximum signal over time?

Comment: weak-sense stationarity would be an important assumption to make, yes. the interesting part would then be the autocorrelation of the signal: If the autocorrelation function is a very smooth one, then less frequent observations would suffice to estimate position and amplitude of the peak. If, on the other extreme, the autocorrelation takes shape of the delta dirac distribution (functional), then your *power spectral density* would be a constant, and you'd need infinitely many, tight packed observations of the instantaneous amplitude to make it work.

Comment: (err, wide-sense stationarity is the right English term, I think)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I think the mean of the random process should change with time, that would should reflect the reality but I'm okay to making some modelling concessions.

So, maybe you could specify some estimators in the answer and I will accept it?

Comment: That's really hard because I know so little about how you expect the signal to be!

Comment: My apologies @MarcusMüller, could you tell me what exactly is the kind of information do you need?

Basically, it's a strain gauge measurement due to a moving load. So the signal is expected to be zero, initially, and peak as the load moves to the position of maximum impact, and then again come back down (to zero usually). I don't have information about the correlation, but I think the signal to be significantly correlated over time. Not the dirac delta function type though.

Does this help?

What else should I add?

Comment: Can you maybe tell us a bit more about the rough time frame of that rise?

Comment: The total time would be about 3 minutes, in which the rise is quite gradual, and so is the decline.

Comment: We're getting close! I'd ideally would want to bound the bandwidth of the signal of interest, so that we can infer what sampling is sufficient to fully be able to reconstruct the original sample. Note that we don't need to do that – fully reconstruct all of the signal – if we have a model formula that we could just parameterize with measurements. But we don't have that, so all we can do is fully reconstruct, and search for the maximum.